# Swift closure not setting variable

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, closures, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set a variable that is outside a closure inside that closure, but it doesn't end up getting set in the end. However, the value that I'm setting the variable to *is* being printed to the console. Also, right after setting the return variable and printing it itself, the correct value is being printed to the console. The problem arises when I return the variable; its value stays the same as the value at initialization. Here is some psuedo-code:

```
let str: String = {
    var ret: String = "default value"

    functionWithClosure(with: (some_name) in {
        if let name = some_name {
            ret = name
            print(name) // prints successfully
            print(ret_name) // also prints successfully
        }
    })

    return ret // returns "default value"
}()
```

This is the actual code that isn't working:

```
let name: String = {
    var ret_name = "default value"

    if let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String {
                    ret_name = name
                    print(ret_name)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    return ret_name
}()
```

Comment: Please mention the error you are getting as well as mention that is it compile time or the runtime error.

Comment: I'm not getting an error. The problem is that `ret` stays as "default value" when returned.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you provide your closure code as well.`functionWithClosure` that you are using.

Comment: I've added more specific code.

Comment: Your closure method is an async method so the return is called before your closure finishes execution. You can check it by debugging the code put break points on `return` line and `print(ret_name)` line the `return` will be called first. Thats why it is returning the default value.

Comment: I see. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142236/discussion-between-archie-gertsman-and-nishant-bhindi).

Comment: Please, if my answer helped, mark it:)

Comment: I still need to try something later today

Comment: Ok. But i know actually that it is correct answer, i m using it every day..) You can check my github profile. SpotMap repo. Model - database. Here is too much API functions. And their calls in controllers. Link in bio

Comment: This didn't fix my particular problem, however I see how it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.observeSingleEvent is working async.

You can do something like this:

```
func getRetname(completion: @escaping(_ retName: String) -> Void) {
    if let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
        FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String {
                ret_name = name
                print(ret_name)
                completion(ret_name)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Then, you can use it everywhere you want:

```
getRetname(completion: { ret_name in 
    // ret_name - your data
})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: How can I make another function return the value of `ret_name`?

Comment: @ArchieGertsman what do you mean?
You can use now getRetname like I wrote below. ret_name is now your printed value

Answer (score 1):

May be below can be the workout for the issue.

```
func getName(completion: @escaping(_ name: String) -> Void) {
if let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
    .child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String {
            completion(name)
        }
    }
})
}
```

Now set the value of string by below code

```
getName(completion: { name in 
     let str = name
 })
```

Comment: mm, check other answers:)